# Keras change the layer names of a save model and get ValueError Graph disconnected

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras

I would like to change layer names of a trained and saved Keras(2.3.1) model as follows: user_embedding_123 and item_embedding_284 are the only two Input layers of the model.

```
from keras.models import load_model, save_model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model

model = load_model('final_model.hdf5')
for layer in model.layers:
    if layer.name == 'user_embedding_123':
        layer.name = 'user_embedding'
    if layer.name == 'item_embedding_284':
        layer.name = 'item_embedding'

save_model(model, "final_model_renamed.hdf5")
model_renamed = load_model('final_model_renamed.hdf5')  # Get an error
```

However I get an error:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("user_embedding:0", shape=(?, 768), dtype=float32) at layer "user_embedding". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

The model summary was like:

```
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
user_embedding_123 (Input (None, 768)          0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
item_embedding_284 (Input (None, 768)          0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 1536)         0           user_embedding_123[0][0]
                                                                 item_embedding_284[0][0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
hidden_0 (Dense)                (None, 256)          393472      concatenate_1[0][0]
......
```

Now it is like:

```
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
user_embedding (InputLayer)  (None, 768)          0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
item_embedding (InputLayer (None, 768)          0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 1536)         0           user_embedding[0][0]
                                                                 item_embedding[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
hidden_0 (Dense)                (None, 256)          393472      concatenate_1[0][0]
```

The model summary looks good, but still get the error. Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

Please try again by modifying `.name` to `._name` during changing the existing name of the model layer.
Like this:

```
if layer.name == 'user_embedding_123':
    layer._name = 'user_embedding'
```

**Please check this same code as an example:**

```
model = load_model('my_model.hdf5')
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential_24"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 Dense1_Layer (Dense)        (None, 512)               401920    
                                                                 
 Dense2_Layer (Dense)        (None, 256)               131328    
                                                                 
 Dense3_Layer (Dense)        (None, 128)               32896     
                                                                 
 Dropout_Layer (Dropout)     (None, 128)               0         
                                                                 
 Dense4_Layer (Dense)        (None, 10)                1290      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 567,434
Trainable params: 567,434
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

To change the specific layer's name:

```
for layer in model.layers:
    if layer.name == 'Dense1_Layer':
        layer._name = 'newDense11'
    if layer.name == 'Dense2_Layer':
        layer._name = 'newDense22'

model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential_24"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 newDense11 (Dense)          (None, 512)               401920    
                                                                 
 newDense22 (Dense)          (None, 256)               131328    
                                                                 
 Dense3_Layer (Dense)        (None, 128)               32896     
                                                                 
 Dropout_Layer (Dropout)     (None, 128)               0         
                                                                 
 Dense4_Layer (Dense)        (None, 10)                1290      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 567,434
Trainable params: 567,434
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Saving and Reloading the model to check the changes

```
save_model(model, "final_model_renamed.hdf5")
model_renamed = load_model('final_model_renamed.hdf5')

model_renamed.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential_24"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 newDense11 (Dense)          (None, 512)               401920    
                                                                 
 newDense22 (Dense)          (None, 256)               131328    
                                                                 
 Dense3_Layer (Dense)        (None, 128)               32896     
                                                                 
 Dropout_Layer (Dropout)     (None, 128)               0         
                                                                 
 Dense4_Layer (Dense)        (None, 10)                1290      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 567,434
Trainable params: 567,434
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```